# Is ptrA = ptrB equivalent to ptrA = &*ptrB?, and do nulls share an address space?

Tags: c++

I have a couple of questions on pointer reassignment, pointer comparison and whether nulls share an address space in Q1, Q2, and Q3 respectively.

```
int main()
{
int var2 = 2;
int varnull = NULL;
int* myPtr_simple = &var2;

//Q1) are these 2 statements equivalent in terms of reassigning 
//both myPtr_long and myPtr_short to what myPtr_simple points to?
int* myPtr_long = &*myPtr_simple;
int* myPtr_short = myPtr_simple;

//Q2) are these 2 statements equivalent?
std::cout<<(myPtr_short==myPtr_long)<<std::endl; //TRUE
std::cout<<(*myPtr_short==*myPtr_long)<<std::endl; //TRUE

//if var2 is non-null
//(address spaces of var2, myPtr_short, myPtr_long are equal)
std::cout<<(&*myPtr_short==&*myPtr_long)<<std::endl; //TRUE
std::cout<<(&*myPtr_short==&var2)<<std::endl; //TRUE
std::cout<<(&var2==&*myPtr_long)<<std::endl; //TRUE

//Q3) if varnull is null
//(myPtr_short and myPtr_long share address space, but not same as varnull...why?)
myPtr_long = NULL;
myPtr_short = NULL;
std::cout<<(&*myPtr_short==&*myPtr_long)<<std::endl; //TRUE
std::cout<<(&*myPtr_short==&varnull)<<std::endl; //FALSE
std::cout<<(&varnull==&*myPtr_long)<<std::endl; //FALSE

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't dereference a NULL pointer.

Comment: Q1). No, if `myPtr_simple` is null, the behaviour of the first is undefined. Q2). No, one is a value comparison and the other a pointer comparison. Q3). `(&*myPtr_short==&*myPtr_long)` is nonsense as both ptrs are null, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Not an answer, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: Why `NULL`? Don't be old-fashioned; use `nullptr`.

Comment: @George Could you kindly explain what exactly is a pointer comparison? I would have thought the compiler would dereference what both pointers are pointing to and compare the values...hence the question. Thanks!

Comment: @jorjor17 Maybe that's dodgy terminology on my part. `(myPtr_short==myPtr_long)` here you are comparing the value of each pointer, if they are pointing at the same thing or are both null the statement will evaluate to true. `(*myPtr_short==*myPtr_long)` will de reference both pointers and compare there values. The standard dictates that comparing the values of pointers will do just that, a C++ complaint compiler is not allowed to change that.

Comment: @ChristianHackl:  `0` is less typing than either `NULL` or `nullptr`.

Comment: `nullptr` is only one char shorter than `(void*)0`, though no shift key required.

Comment: @Kaz: That does not matter. Code quality is not measured in typing speed. Use `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1) are these 2 statements equivalent in terms of reassigning both myPtr_long and myPtr_short to what myPtr_simple points to?
>
> ```
> int* myPtr_long = &*myPtr_simple;
> int* myPtr_short = myPtr_simple;
> ```

Yes, these have the same effect.

> Q2) are these 2 statements equivalent?
>
> ```
> std::cout<<(myPtr_short==myPtr_long)<<std::endl; //TRUE
> std::cout<<(*myPtr_short==*myPtr_long)<<std::endl; //TRUE
> ```

No, definitely not. `myPtr_short==myPtr_long` checks whether `myPtr_short` and `myPtr_long` are pointers to the same object. (This is not entirely true, but close enough for now.) `*myPtr_short==*myPtr_long` checks whether both referenced objects hold the same value.

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
int* pi = &i;
int* pj = &j;
```

Now, `pi == pj`  is not true. `pi` and `pj` point to different objects.

But `*pi == *pj` is true, since both `i` and `j` happen to have the value `0`, and `0 == 0` is obviously true.

> Q3) if varnull is null (myPtr_short and myPtr_long share address space, but not same as varnull...why?)
>
> ```
> myPtr_long = NULL;
> myPtr_short = NULL;
> std::cout<<(&*myPtr_short==&*myPtr_long)<<std::endl; //TRUE
> std::cout<<(&*myPtr_short==&varnull)<<std::endl; //FALSE
> ```

`&*myPtr_short` and `&*myPtr_long` are just `myPtr_short` and `myPtr_long`. They're both `NULL`, as that's the value you just assigned to them.

`&varnull` *isn't* `NULL`: it's a valid pointer to an object. What value you've used to initialise that object is irrelevant, as this doesn't check `varnull`'s value.

Comment: This is super helpful thanks! I guess &varnull isn't NULL as it has a dedicated address space reserved for an int. And your answer to Q2 has really clarified my understanding of pointers very much.

Comment: @jorjor17 Yes, `varnull` is a variable of type `int`, and `&varnull` is a pointer to that variable, so it holds an address reserved for storing an `int` into. `myPtr_short` doesn't, as `NULL` is not an address reserved for storing an `int` into, nor any other value. (Note: the term "address space" has a specific meaning, and it doesn't sound like that specific meaning is the one you're going for, so I've tried to avoid that term in my answer and comment. I may have misunderstood what you meant by it though.)

Comment: @jorjor17, also note that `int varnull = NULL;` is the same that `int varnull = 0;` you are not creating a "NULL pointer to int", but an integer with value = 0